# Creating a Minimal Shared Library

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

For background, I'm creating some C++ software that uses dynamically loaded shared library plugins for hardware output (the specifics of it aren't relevant here).

I'm building the executable by compiling everything into object files and then linking the ones needed, which is simple using an exclusion list. I can then build the shared library by specifying its primary object file (the one that's dynamically loaded and accessed at runtime) along with every other object file referenced by the primary one.

My question is this: Is there a way to provide the linker with the primary object file, and create a shared library containing only the objects it depends upon? All of the object files are in the same directory, I'm not using a Makefile (yet; if one could solve the problem, it's a valid answer), and compilation speed isn't an issue.

I've looked into the linker options `--as-needed`, `--gc-sections`, and `--no-undefined`, but I haven't been able to piece together a working build process.

Example: For source files `main.cpp`, `a.cpp`, `b.cpp`, `a.h`, and `b.h`, where `main.cpp` and `a.cpp` both include `b.h`:

`gcc -fPIC -c *.cpp -I.` builds object files `main.o`, `a.o`, and `b.o`.

`gcc -o main.out *.o` builds the final executable `main.out` from the object files... **including a.o, which is unused.** (`--gc-sections` should fix this.)

`gcc -fPIC -shared -o a.so a.o -Wl,--as-needed !(a).o` builds the final shared library `a.so` from all of the object files... **including main.o, which is unused**. How do I prevent `main.o` from being included in `a.so`?

Comment: It seems to me that your whole problem comes from not explicitly listing which files go into what. I recommend using autotools, CMake, a plain old Makefile, or even a shell script. But use something.

Comment: I'm currently using a shell script, which doesn't explicitly list (most) files; the issue is that the plugins are interchangeable but all build into the same directory with the main executable, so I end up with a few extra objects in the shared libraries if I don't use dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to provide the linker with the primary object file, and create a shared library containing only the objects it depends upon?

Yes: package all objects into an archive library `liball.a`, then link like this:

```
gcc -shared -o a.so a.o liball.a
```

The linker will then pull out from `liball.a` all objects that `a.o` depends on, and *only* these objects, as explained [here](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

Note: `liball.a` may contain `a.o`, there is no harm (as above link explains).

**Update:**

> Is there a way to do it without needing to create an archive first?

I don't know of any portable way to do that. The [Gold linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) has `--start-lib` and `--end-lib` command line flags that [achieve exactly that](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2010-03/msg00233.html).

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I wanted; my goal was to create a shared library containing both `a.o` and its dependencies (sorry, that was a bit unclear). Is there a way to do it without needing to create an archive first?